# Ruby - catch all network exceptions

Tags: ruby, networking, rescue

What's the best way to catch all network related problems?

The exception is handled some layers above (it can be thrown from various places, and that's the right place to handle it) and I obviously don't want to catch it as a generic exception, because that could mask other problems.

I hope somebody encountered this problem before. This is my current list (but I fear it's not complete):

```
rescue Timeout::Error, Net::HTTPServerException, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH, Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::ENETUNREACH, Errno::ETIMEDOUT
```

Comment: Just a first step, but `SystemCallError` takes all `Errno` exceptions. But you may not want to catch all `Errno` either...

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370697/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-exceptions-from-nethttp