# How to handle exceptions in own method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, rescue

How can I handle exceptions in its own method instead of this?

```
items.each do |item|
  begin
    url = item.url
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Couldn't read \"#{ url }\": #{ e }"
  else
    title = get_title(page)
  end
end
```

Something like:

```
def get_page(url)
  begin
    Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Couldn't read \"#{ url }\": #{ e }"
  end
end

#and then call:

items.each do |item|
 get_page(url)
 title = get_title(page)
end
```

Where should I place the `else` clause?

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question, it's a Ruby exception handling question.

Comment: @theTinMan I think so, it's a Ruby question. Did I use wrong title or tag?

Comment: You tagged it as Nokogiri. While Nokogiri is mentioned in the code, it's not important as the question is about handling exceptions. If this was about handling Nokogiri-specific exceptions then tagging Nokogiri would make sense, otherwise tagging OpenURI or Kernel would make more sense since those supply the `open` behavior which would raise an exception reading a file. It's all about understanding your code and what gems/libraries supply what.

Comment: @theTinManI completely agree with you. I didn't remember that I tagged as Nokogiri. And yes, OpenURI tag gas more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you almost never want to rescue from `Exception`. Instead rescue from `StandardError` (or the specific errors). `Exception` is an ancestor of `StandardError` and includes errors that are most likely not recoverable (out of memory error, syntax error, for example).

You can use

```
rescue => e
```

to rescue from standard error or

```
rescue StandardError => e
```

Any type of Nokogiri parsing error should inherit from `StandardError`. Net/HTTP is a little more problematic. See "[What’s the best way to handle exceptions from Net::HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370697/what-s-the-best-way-to-handle-exceptions-from-nethttp)", but you can just rescue them individually.

Now to your question. You could return `nil` from your `get_page` method and check to see if the result of `get_page` is `nil` before getting the title:

```
def get_page(url)
  Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
rescue => e
  puts "Couldn't read \"#{ url }\": #{ e }"
  nil
end

items.each do |item|
  url = item.url
  page = get_page(url)

  if page
    title = get_title(page)
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer. Please edit it and change Exception => e in code.