# Ruby HTTP post request authorization in header

Tags: ruby, api

I'm trying to write some scripts in Ruby to interface with Guild Wars 2's API (https://api.guildwars2.com/v2)

At the bottom of that page it has this info:

> APIs which require authentication need to be passed an API key belonging to
>   the account to be accessed. The API key must have the appropriate permissions
>   associated with it (/v2/tokeninfo can be used to inspect key permissions). Keys
>   can be generated on the ArenaNet account site.
>
> Keys can be passed either via query parameter or HTTP header. Our servers do
>   not support preflighted CORS requests, so if your application is running
>   in the user's browser you'll need to user the query parameter.
>
> To pass via query parameter, include "?access_token=" in your request.
>
> To pass via HTTP header, include "Authentication: Bearer (API key)".

The code I'm working with right now is as follows:

```
class Gw2
  attr_reader :response, :uri, :http

  def initialize
    @uri = URI.parse('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2')

    @http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    @http.use_ssl = true

    @http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end

  def wallet
    path ="/v2/account/wallet"
    @response = @http.get(path).body
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to go about setting that up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add \`Authorization Bearer\` hash to Net::HTTP post request (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032890/add-authorization-bearer-hash-to-nethttp-post-request-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://some.url')

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
req.add_field('X-Forwarded-For', '0.0.0.0')
# For content type, you could also use content_type=(type, params={})
# req.set_form_data({'query' => 'search me'})
# req['X-Forwarded-For'] = '0.0.0.0'

res = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

puts res.body
```