# How to do a simple GraphQL query in a native Ruby script

Tags: ruby, graphql

I'm trying to figure out how to do a simple GraphQL query without using gems. The following `cURL` commands works

```
curl -X POST "https://gql.example.com/graphql/public" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "query": "query { user { id defaultEmail } }", "variables": {} }'
```

and the corresponding javascript code is

```
fetch('https://gql.example.com/graphql/public', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: 'query { user { id defaultEmail } }',
    variables: {}
  })
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Is it possible to do this easily in Ruby without using the `graphql` gem? I only need to do simple queries like the examples above so I'm hoping it's easy to do them in a single Ruby script.

Comment: You can try using Faraday gem but is same like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ruby core lib Net/HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-POST) and build your requests like so:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('https://gql.example.com/graphql/public')
params = {'query': 'query { user { id defaultEmail } }', 'variables': {} }
headers = {
    "Authorization'=>'Bearer #{ENV['MY_ACCESS_TOKEN']}", 
    'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
    'Accept'=>'application/json'
}

https = Net::HTTPS.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = https.post(uri.path, params.to_json, headers)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41033447/3625433) as well